# Global variable in a recursive function how to keep it at zero?

Tags: java, recursion

So if I have a recursive function with a global variable var_:

```
int var_;

void foo()
{
  if(var_ == 3)
    return;
  else
    var_++; foo();
}
```

and then I have a function that calls foo() so:

```
void bar()
{
  foo();
  return;
}
```

what is the best way to set var_ =0 everytime foo is called thats not from within itself.  I know I could just do:

```
void bar()
{
  var_ =0;
  foo();
  return;
}
```

but I'm using the recursive function a lot and I don't want to call foo and forget to set var_=0 at a later date.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn `foo()` into a helper function.

```
void foo() {
    var_ = 0;
    foo_helper();
}

void foo_helper() {
    if(var_ == 3)
        return;
    else
        var_++; foo_helper();
}
```

You won't have to change any existing code, and you can still just call `foo()` and let it do its work.

Comment: Thank you for the input, this is what I was thinking too but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would split `foo()` into an initializing function, and the true recursive function:

```
void foo()
{
    var_ = 0;
    foo_recur();
}

void foo_recur()
{
  if(var_ == 3)
    return;
  else
    var_++; foo_recur();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the first two (amazingly similar) answers that you got, make only the foo() method visible from outside your class and keep the foo_helper() / foo_recur() as private (the var_ should also be private). If this is meant to be used in a multi-threaded environment, you should also make foo() synchronized.

Also, it's better to call "var_" an instance- or class- variable (instead of "global").

Comment: Always good suggestions. I'm not sure his requirements, so I'm not sure if they fit, but they are all good things to note. +1

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need this global variable?

If it's used only to control the depth of recursion, you can rewrite it in more elegant way, as follows:

```
void foo()  {
    fooHelper(0);
}

void fooHelper(int var) {
    if (var == 3) return;
    else fooHelper(var + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the var is not about controlling the depth, I need it to match a specific node an xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

To let the function know whether it was called from within itself, you can add a parameter:

```
int var_;

void foo(boolean from_itself)
{
 if(!from_itself)
  var_ = 0;
 if(var_ == 3)
  return;
 else
  var_++; foo(true);  // from within itself
}

void bar()
{
 foo(false);  // not from within itself
 return;
}
```

So this approach doesn't require adding a helper function.