# using same variable in recursion

Tags: java

I'm trying to apply the flood fill on a specific question. I'm having a hard time understanding how to create a variable with a help function so I keep it throughout all the recursion.
I've seen there is a thread about it though I don't know how to apply it for my own use.

This is the code I wrote so far:

how do I create the k variable to stay the same?

```
public static int[][] fill(int[][] map, int i, int j, int color) {
    int[][] ans = null;

    if ((i<map.length)&&(i>0)&&(j<map.length)&&(j>0))
    {
        if ((k!=map[i][j]))
        {
            map[i][j]=color;    
        }
    }
    fill(map,i-1,j,color);
    fill(map,i+1,j,color);
    fill(map,i,j-1,color);
    fill(map,i,j+1,color);
    return ans;
}

public static void fill(int[][] map, int i, int j, int color,int k)

k=map[i][j]
```

lets say this is my array:

4, 1, 2, 2
4, 4, 3, 1
1, 4, 4, 4

1, 4, 0, 2

and I wish to flood fill all the indexes that have the value of 4.
I wish k to obtain the value of 4 so I can use k to compare in each index.

Comment: Where is `k` defined? Please post some code that compiles, preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't know your needs (maybe you could explain better), but if you want a variable available to all the recursive calls to a function, that means you need an additional parameter.

Comment: and what is this thead you are talking about? is it another question on StackOverflow?

Comment: im trying to define k but I don't quite understand as explained here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672035/global-variable-in-a-recursive-function-how-to-keep-it-at-zero

Comment: im supposed to use a help function that defines k, but where exactly do I use it? inside the main function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iמ Addition to your question i have noticed that your function wont work because you boundries checking, you are check if row or col are equal to the board length , its alright but you need  to change it to <, and not <= . anyway you can use your code like that :

```
public static int[][] fill(int[][] map, int i, int j, int color) {

    int origColor = map[i][j];
    fill(map, i, j, color, origColor);


    return map;

    }

private static void fill(int[][] map, int i, int j,int color, int   origColor) {



    //checks if index is inside matrix and if the index is equal to original   number.

    if ((i<map.length)&&(i>=0)&&(j<map.length)&&(j>=0)&&(origColor==map[i][j]))

    {

    map[i][j]=color;



    //recursive call for north east west south.

    fill(map,i-1,j,color,origColor);

    fill(map,i+1,j,color,origColor);

    fill(map,i,j-1,color,origColor);

    fill(map,i,j+1,color,origColor);
    }


    }
 public static void printBoard(int[][] board) {
if (board == null)
    System.out.println("null");
else for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
    if (board[i] == null)
        System.out.println("null");
    else
        for (int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++) 
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

for checking :

```
fill(map,1,1,9);
    printBoard(map);
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You would use new function that gets the value for k (I'm calling it origColor in the example) and then passes it the the function that needs it. The function using k does not need to be visible from the outside unless you also want to, so I made it private below.

```
public static void fill(int[][] map, int i, int j, int color) {
  int origColor = map[i][j];
  fill(map, i, j, color, origColor);
}

private static void fill(int[][] map, int i, int j, int color, int origColor) {
  // actual fill method with recursive calls.
}
```

Comment: I see but I still don't quite understand which of the functions runs first? I call the main function through the help function??